# Adding a 3D carousel to Shopify

Tags: jquery, css, shopify

I want to add this 3D carousel that I recently purchased on my Shopify website.

This is what how it looks like:

http://www.codingjack.com/carousel/thumbs.html

They've provided the code and everything but the reason I'm asking it here is because my programmer fell sick to a viral fever and can no longer continue. He was in the middle of installing this.

I'm not a programmer myself but I have my website's presentation to a very big company in 2 days and I'm stuck here with code in my hand not knowing what to do with it.

Can someone please guide me in installing this on my website? Please keep in mind that I would be needing explanation as a layman :(

Comment: Why not just pay someone and free yourself from the burden of trying to do something you cannot do?

Comment: I did approach a few freelancers. Nobody agrees to doing it in just 2 days. A few even said it cannot be done. A few were charging wayyyy more than expected. Trust me, I wouldn't be here if I hadn't exhausted all my resources. If it weren't for the presentation I would simply wait and find the best person to do it.